# Operator overload for ostream not working with user defined class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, ostream

I have this simple program and when i try to **`cout << 75.0_stC ;`** i have multiple errors and i don't know why.This things only happen when i pass my temperature object via reference.

```
class temperature
{
    public:
        long double degrees;
        temperature(long double c): degrees{c}{}
        long double show()const {return degrees;}

};
temperature operator"" _stC(long double t){
    return temperature(t);
}
ostream & operator<<(ostream &ekran, temperature &t)
{
    ekran << t.show();
    return ekran;
}
```

Comment: Pass `temperature` as `const&`: https://godbolt.org/z/Pzzbfj7zE.

Comment: `ostream&` parameter makes sense, because the stream is modified (*mutated*) by the operation.  `temperature&` parameter does not make sense; why is `cout << t` **modifying** the temperature parameter?  That is what the non-const *reference* tells in the signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely need to take a `const` reference to the argument you'd like to print:

```
ostream & operator<<(ostream &ekran, const temperature &t)
```

Temporary won't bind to the non-const reference argument.